# Fundamental & essential matrix in javascript

Tags: javascript, opencv, image-processing, transformation

I've been looking for an implementation of **essential matrix and fundamental matrix in javascript** for a while but can't find anything. I'm basically looking for 
https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/calib3d/src/fundam.cpp#L763-L826, LMEDS implementation to be more specific and the similar `findEssentialMat`. I've looked at a couple of libraries - nudged, jsfeat, etc. but they weren't helpful. I'm trying to avoid including entire openCV.js because it's too big.

PS: Ideally, I'd just want to build opencv for the functions I need and core utils but it's not documented anywhere apparently.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using [math.js](http://mathjs.org/docs/datatypes/matrices.html)?

Comment: Just checked it out. It only has basic functions for maths, doesn't look like an image processing library. There are several other libraries to do matrix manipulation that I could use to write the fundamental matrix calculation but I'm trying to avoid errors and re-inventing the wheel.